# bubblesort ctype sort Python

Tags: python, ctype

For homework i'm trying to make a ctype array and pass it into a bubble sort and return my array.  I created the array just fine

```
arrSize = int(input("How many numbers? "))
nums = (arrSize*ctypes.py_object)(*range(arrSize))
random.shuffle(nums)
print(nums[:])
```

and when i pass it into my bubble sort i get: <**main**.py_object_Array_15 object at 0x0000000003949BC8>
Here is  my bubblesort code.

```
def bubbleSort(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for k in range(len(array) -1, i, -1):
            if (array[k] < array[k-1]):
                swap(array, k, k-1)
                return array

def swap(a, x, y):
    tmp = a[x]
    a[x] = a[y]
    a[y] = tmp
```

the code that i run to make it work "sorta" is

```
result = bubbleSort(nums)
print(result)
```

does anybody know where im going wrong ive been looking at this for so ling i'm going cross eyed

Comment: what is `ctypes.py_object`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if getting

```
<main.py_object_Array_15 object at 0x0000000003949BC8>
```

as the result is your **only problem**, then you should

```
print (list ( result))
```

Comment: Wow thanks that fixed my problem now i can continue with this thing

Comment: oh like what im not a strong program by any stretch of the imagination so im sure there are some